# Elequoent relationship is not selecting releated rows

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 tables: `products` and `images`

**Products table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price_standard` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_life` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_multi` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_addon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `banner_style` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'blue'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `name`, `short_description`, `description`, `price_standard`, `price_life`, `price_multi`, `product_addon`, `banner_style`) VALUES
(16, '2017-02-12 19:25:03', '2017-02-12 19:25:03', NULL, 'tet', 'test', 'test', 100, 200, 330, 0, 'blue');
```

**Image table**

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `images`
--

INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `product_id`, `image_name`) VALUES
(1, '2017-02-12 19:25:03', '2017-02-12 19:25:03', 16, '58a0b68fd1d1b.jpg');
```

I have 2 models, a products model and the images model, I am trying to select the images for the products, but I am getting 'exists false'

**Products Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function features()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductFeatures');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return$this->hasMany('App\Images', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Images model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Images extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';
}
```

The controller I am using to get all the products images:

```
public function getProduct(Product $product)
{
    // get the product addons
    $addons = $product->where('product_addon', $product->id)->get();

    dd($product->images());

    return View('pages.product.view-item')->withProduct($product)->withAddons($addons);
}
```

And the route in my web.php

```
Route::get('item/{product}', 'ProductsController@getProduct');
```

But when I diedump to see if the image is being selected I get the following under the image mapping:

```
  #related: Images {#219 ▼
    #table: "images"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #events: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
```

How come it is not selecting the images for the product 16, but it is selecting the data from the products table?

Comment: I figured it out. I was initiating it like so: $product->images()->, rather than $product->image->, the latter gets the items... So if someone wants to explain in an answer the reasoning, in case anyone in the future struggles from the same thing. I wll mark as best answer. (give a good answer not a few lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$product->images` instead of `$product->images()`.

When you call the relation as a function it returns the relation query object which you can use to add additional query constraints to, but it doesn't seem like that's what you want here. At that point though you still need to execute the query object to get the data.

When you call the relation as a property off the model eloquent will automatically execute the sql and get the data.

So these two lines should produce the same result

```
$product->images

$product->images()->get()
```